# How to measure intel gpu's memory uage on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpu

I found a commond called `intel_gpu_top` but it does not give any information about memory - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/intel_gpu_top.1.html.

Is there any command to check intel GPU's memory usage like `nvidia-smi` for NVIDIA GPUs?

Comment: Try `sudo intel_gpu_top` and `glxinfo`.

Comment: `glxinfo | grep -i 'video memory'` (from https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mesa-utils) unfortunately just reports how much memory my system has AKA the iGPU can use *all* the system memory. I think we really want to know how much is currently allocated and how much of that is used (like what `radeontop` gives for AMD).

Answer (score -3):

You can use Gnome System Monitor.
That is a useful tool for Linux.

[Gnome System Monitor](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-and-use-task-manager-system-monitor-in-ubuntu/)

You can visit and install this tool.

If you don't want install a graphical tool. You can use htop.

[htop Using](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/using-htop-to-monitor-system-processes-on-linux/)

Comment: `htop` doesn't have a GPU-memory meter or per-process column that I noticed in the help.  I have htop 3.0.3 on Arch GNU/Linux, i7-6700k (Skylake) with integrated GPU, running htop in a `konsole` terminal window under X11 with working open-source Intel 3D drivers.  Are you just suggested system-monitoring tools in general, not GPU?

Comment: I mentioned intel's GPU, not CPU.